# CG Optimisation Function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I need to prove the following statement:

> Given the unique minimiser $\overline{x}$ of the function $f(x) := \frac{1}{2}<Ax,x> + <b,x> + c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$. Prove that $f(x) = f(\overline{x}) + \frac{1}{2}\vert\vert x-\overline{x} \vert\vert_A^2$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

So far I got to this point:
$\begin{align*}
                f(\overline{x}) + \frac{1}{2}\vert\vert{x - \overline{x}}\vert\vert_A^2 &= \frac{1}{2}\overline{x}^TA\overline{x} + \overline{x}^Tb + c + \frac{1}{2}((x-\overline{x})^TA(x-\overline{x})) \\
                &= \frac{1}{2}\overline{x}^TA\overline{x} + \overline{x}^Tb + c + \frac{1}{2}(x^TAx - x^TA\overline{x} - \overline{x}^TAx + \overline{x}^TA\overline{x}) \\
                &= \frac{1}{2}\overline{x}^TA\overline{x} + \overline{x}^Tb + c + \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb + \frac{1}{2}\overline{x}^TA\overline{x} \\
                &= \overline{x}^TA\overline{x} + \overline{x}^Tb + c + \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb \\
                &= \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb + c + 2\overline{x}^Tb
            \end{align*}$

How can I get $<b,x>$ from $2\overline{x}^Tb - x^Tb$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}< Ax,x > + < b,x > + c$ the equality $f(x) = f(\overline{x}) + \frac{1}{2}\vert\vert x - \overline{x}\vert\vert_A^2$ can not hold. It holds only for the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} < Ax,x > - < b,x > + c$.

Comment: I do not understand why this answer is the accepted one. Clearly both statements are equivalent (put in $-b$ in the last statement).

Comment: @LinAlg The statements in this answer are equivalent. But not the ones in the original post/question. If you think the ones in the original post are also equivalent, post your proof

Comment: in this answer you say "for the function ... the equality ... can not hold". That is not true. In the last comment of my answer I told you how to fix it (add two minus signs).

Comment: @LinAlg For $A = [1]$, $b = [1]$ the solution for the linear system is given by $\overline{x} = [1]$. But $f(0) = c < f(\overline{x})$. That means that $\overline{x}$ is not a minimiser of the function $f$, even though it is the solution of the linear system $Ax = b$. I defined the function $f$ in the first post wrong. Again, if you have a better solution, post your **complete** proof. Thank you

Comment: for $0.5x^TAx + b^Tx + c$, the linear system is $Ax+b=0$, so the solution in your example is $\bar{x}=-1$, with $f(\bar{x})=c-0.5$. For your original question, the functions $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}< Ax,x > - < b,x > + c$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}< Ax,x > + < b,x > + c$ are essentially the same, because you can always take the $b$ from one of those two functions, and plug in $-b$ into the other one.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an error in your third equality, because you cannot get from $2\overline{x}^Tb - x^Tb$ to $<b,x>$ (since $\overline{x}$ depends on $A$). It goes well until the expression right before that:

$$\overline{x}^TA\overline{x} + \overline{x}^Tb + c + \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^TA\overline{x},$$

but I do not see what the next step was that you took. If you plug in the expression for $\overline{x}$ (you can explicitly write the minimizer in terms of $A$ and $b$), you should arrive at the solution.

Comment: I still can't see what I did wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @Nick can you elaborate in your question what you did in the last step?

Comment: I have just edited it

Comment: @Nick I still do not see what you did in the last step

Comment: $A\overline{x} = b$ so $\overline{x}^TA\overline{x} = \overline{x}^Tb$

Comment: @Nick there is a missing negative sign: taking the derivative gives $A\bar{x}+b=0$. That also went wrong in the third step. If you fix both steps, you get the answer.